# Leaving only the first value (for a specific value) but creating zeros for all the other rows that have the same value

Tags: r

```
 post_date   post_age  former_customer  *former_customer_new*
2016-11-27     1309         20.01632        20.01632 
2016-11-27     1309         20.01632         0
2016-11-26     1310         22.98056        22.98056
2016-11-26     1310         22.98056         0
2016-11-26     1310         22.98056         0
2016-11-26     1310         22.98056         0
```

I am looking for the code that creates the last column in which the value per day is shown only in the first row, but indicates a 0 for the other rows in which the day is the same.
In the end I want to create a cumulative variable but with counting the value per day only ONCE and not multiple times. If there is a better solution (and there probably is one) please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(post_date) %>% mutate(former_cust_new = ifelse(row_number() == 1, former_customer, 0)) %>% ungroup()
```

for demonstration please add some data